# Why do we use pumping lemma to prove the non-regularity of languages? WHY?

Tags: regular-language, dfa, nfa, pumping-lemma

I am currently working on the usage of pumping lemma and I need to know why do we use pumping lemma? the main question asked is why?
I know we can prove the non-regularity and I know the formula/proof as well, I'd just like to ask why?

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged [regex]. Please only use tags that are relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the Pumping Lemma *IFF* we can use it, because *in those cases where we can use it*, it provides much shorter and simpler proofs than other alternative proof methods.